# Openpyxl error - Valueerror {0} is not a valid coordinate or range

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to write a list to an excel column and encounter an error.  I am attempting to write each value of matchingName to the worksheet aSheet in column V.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/smartCompare/excelmain.py", line 40, in 
>       aSheet[V] = matchingName[i3]
>     File 
>   "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 380, in **setitem**
>       self[key].value = value
>     File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 357, in **getitem**
>       min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(key)
>     File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\cell.py", line 129, in range_boundaries
>       raise ValueError("{0} is not a valid coordinate or range")
>   ValueError: {0} is not a valid coordinate or range

Process finished with exit code 1

This error seems to be occurring in the for loop. I checked the [openpyxl](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/_modules/openpyxl/utils/cell.html) documentation but no luck on solving it. Any advice?

```
import openpyxl
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

fruit = []
fruit2 = []
compareScore = []
matchingName = []
matchingRatioNum = []
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
aSheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('AMIS')
cSheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('CMMS')

for col in aSheet['F']:
    fruit.append(col.value)

for col in cSheet['E']:
    fruit2.append(col.value)

length = 5
length2 = 5
i = 0
i2 = 0

for i in range(0, length):
    for i2 in range(0, length2):
        ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, fruit[i], fruit2[i2]).ratio()
        compareScore.append(ratio)
        i2 += 1
    matchRatio = compareScore.index(max(compareScore))
    match = fruit2[matchRatio]
    ratioNum = compareScore[matchRatio]
    matchingName.append(match)
    matchingRatioNum.append(ratioNum)
    compareScore = []
    i += 1

i3 = 0
for i3 in range(0, length):
    V = "'" + 'V' + str(i3+1) + "'"
    aSheet[V] = matchingName[i3]
    del V
    i3 += 1

i4 = 0
for i4 in range(0, length):
    W = "'" + 'W' + str(i4+1) + "'"
    aSheet[W] = matchingRatioNum[i4]
    del W
    i4 += 1
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Full traceback required.

Comment: @CharlieClark added full traceback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating lookups like this `ws["'W4'"]` which are invalid coordinates, you want `ws["W4"]`. You should **always** use `ws.cell()` for programmatic access.

Comment: In my case, I was writing cell number as `ws[" W4"]` . So, I trimmed whitespaces, then it worked.