# Save to Excel with invalid coordinate or range

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have this script that writes to a Excel sheet, I'm using `openpyxl` but I'm getting an error. Here's my cod:

```
 ws['A{0}'.format(str(row2sav))] = rowid
 ws['A{0}'.format(str(row2sav))].fill = PatternFill(bgColor="#7EB33D", fill_type="solid")
```

I get

> ValueError: A9  is not a valid coordinate or range

But `row2sav` is 9 so the A9 is correct. Why do I get this error?

this (ws['A{0}'.format(str(row2sav))] = rowid) works when i create the file but then later on when i open the file and try to save value to it it wont work, am i opening the file right?

```
wb = load_workbook(os.path.join('Reports', filename_report))
    if "fromger" in tipo:
        ws = wb['Central to ChargeStation']
        ws['A8'] = "testing"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Openpyxl error - Valueerror {0} is not a valid coordinate or range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981991/openpyxl-error-valueerror-0-is-not-a-valid-coordinate-or-range)

Comment: Try `ws['\x41{0}'.format(row2sav)]`, where `\x41` is a HEX code of `A` letter

Comment: please attach a bit more code than that. including rowid value, ws init etc. so one can take your code and run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

weird. I tried your first line and it worked just fine.
maybe you have a special character next to A or in row2sav.
to debug it I would suggest to do it in steps.
first do:

```
ws['A9'] = 'test'
```

to check if it works. if it does, start replacing one by one the hard-coded string with their variables and then you can figure out where the problem is.

Comment: your right, like that it works when i create the file, but forward in the program when i need to open it and save the data it wont work, am i missing something opening the file?                       wb = load_workbook(os.path.join('Reports', filename_report))


    if "geradorteste" in tipo:
        ws = wb['Central to ChargeStation']